# how to : Reinstall Windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I installed linux ubuntu last month and everything got messed up . When I first tried it , everything works fine. It's fast and convenient so I decided to install it permanently but after permanently installing it , my computer hangs frequently and then one day, when I turned on my pc, the computer isn't logging in . Then there is this . . . GRUB Rescue > No Partition .
Can I install windows again ? if yes then how ?

Comment: I don't have. Can I use a usb ?

Comment: you can. But in any case you need to have windows 7 installation ISO/files, how to get __that__ is not a topic in this site.

Comment: Thanks for answering . I know where ,what and how to get those so we can refrain those things in here. all i want to know is If i can. btw, thanks again cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Before giving up on your system, you may also want to try any of a number of tools that automagically repairs boot problems. For example:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Otherwise, you can re-install windows with the appropriate installer image (CD/DVD).